# Can an individual investor easily trade options for NASDAQ-CM equities?

Tags: options, nasdaq

When I look at a NASDAQ-CM-listed company on my broker's site (or on Yahoo/Google Finance pages), there are no option prices listed.

Is there some way for an individual investor to buy/sell puts/calls on NASDAQ-CM shares?  Or is that too nichey?

Comment: Are you just looking for brokers to trade options? Have you googled them?

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev I'm looking to trade options for those equities listed on the NASDAQ Capital Market (formerly known as the NASDAQ SmallCap Market). It's the lowest tier of the NASDAQ Stock Market (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASDAQ_Capital_Market and http://www.venturelawcorp.com/listing_requirements_nasdaq.html ).  There don't seem to be [m]any brokers who deal in such instruments.